# Multithreading Merge Sort -> How to optimize?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I tried to multithread the merge sort algorithm. The simple form of the algorithm is: (Merge() is a standart merge algorithm)

```
static void MergeSort(this int[] array, int initial, int final) {
    if (initial == final) return;
    array.MergeSort(initial, (initial + final) / 2);
    array.MergeSort((initial + final) / 2 + 1, final);
    array.Merge(initial, final);
}
```

And the multithreaded version is:

```
static void MergeSortMT(this int[] array, int initial, int final, int mtCount) {
    if (initial == final) return;

    if (mtCount > 0) {
        Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            array.MergeSortMT(initial, (initial + final) / 2, mtCount - 1);
        });
        array.MergeSortMT((initial + final) / 2 + 1, final, mtCount - 1);

        t.Wait();
    }
    else
    {
        array.MergeSort(initial, (initial + final) / 2);
        array.MergeSort((initial + final) / 2 + 1, final);
    }
    array.Merge(initial, final);
}
```

mtCount here indicates that how many times will the thread seperation will happen. Normally whole sort is run by a single thread. If mtCount is 1 total thread number becomes 2, if mtCount is 2 total thread number becomes 4 and so on.

Here are some results:

```
Method - Input Size - Times Run - Miliseconds

Merge 1000000 X 1000    606832
Merge 100000 X 1000     51061
Merge 10000 X 1000      4080
Merge 1000 X 1000       314
Merge 100 X 1000        22
Merge 10 X 1000         1

mtCount = 1
MergeMT 1000000 X 1000  258237
MergeMT 100000 X 1000   23498
MergeMT 10000 X 1000    2088
MergeMT 1000 X 1000     202
MergeMT 100 X 1000      57
MergeMT 10 X 1000       44

mtCount = 2
MergeMT 1000000 X 1000  188337
MergeMT 100000 X 1000   16836
MergeMT 10000 X 1000    1825
MergeMT 1000 X 1000     355
MergeMT 100 X 1000      162
MergeMT 10 X 1000       299

mtCount = 3
MergeMT 1000000 X 1000  175220
MergeMT 100000 X 1000   15276
MergeMT 10000 X 1000    1690
MergeMT 1000 X 1000     455
MergeMT 100 X 1000      296
MergeMT 10 X 1000       416

mtCount = 4
MergeMT 1000000 X 1000  197234
MergeMT 100000 X 1000   17046
MergeMT 10000 X 1000    2087
MergeMT 1000 X 1000     684
MergeMT 100 X 1000      657
MergeMT 10 X 1000       596
```

So using 2 threads optimizes the code more than 2 fold. Using 4 threads affects is less and 8 threads does barely any good. Using 16 threads even decreases performance which is understandable. (Small input sizes are not important. I know that spinning up a new thread takes some time.)

Knowing that my computer has 4 physical cores and 8 threads, my question is that why using 4 or 8 threads increases performance much less?

Comment: I use Stopwatch class  in System.Diagnostics to calculate time. If i run ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads);
workerThreads is set to 8.

Comment: "I know that spinning up a new thread takes some time", have you don't answered your own question?

Comment: @Ferus7 Th reason why low input sizes last longer is the time required to assign the task to a thread but this time is constant throughout the same mtCounts since it creates same amount of threads and is neglegable in greater input sizes.

Comment: "Multithreading Merge Sort -> How to optimize?" - Use a single thread.

Comment: Have you tried to parallelize with the task parallel library (TPL)?

Comment: "my computer has 4 physical cores" as @Sefe tips, if you want to distribute the work between the cores, you shoul'd use the TPL

Comment: You could try to stream the last merge steps so they can start before the previous sort has finished.

Comment: That is a great idea. I might look into that @JeremyLakeman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because merge sort consists of 2 main parts:

1. Recursively sorting 2 halves
2. Merging 2 sorted halves

Multithreading in merge sort is effective because two threads can execute 2 different calls in the first step asynchronously. However, the second step cannot be made faster by multithreading because it is a linear process that has to run on a single thread. And the 2nd step actually takes considerable time. For example, the last(and largest), merge call takes approximately one-third of the entire sorting duration.